# cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ebms_2.Models.PRItems>' to 'ebms_2.Models.PRItems'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012, mvc-editor-templates

I'm getting this error:

-cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'ebms_2.Models.PRItems'

-The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(ebms_2.Models.PRItems)' has some invalid arguments

This is my code

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Consumables(PRSelectionViewModel model)
    {
        int[] selectedIds = model.getSelectedIds().ToArray();
        int num = selectedIds.Length;
        int tmp;

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            tmp = selectedIds[i];
            PRItemsRepository pritemRepo = new PRItemsRepository();
            List<PRItems> listPr = pritemRepo.GetItems();
            listPr.Add(pritemRepo.GetPRdetailItem(tmp).ToList());


            return RedirectToAction("AddPurchaseRequest");

        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

REPOSITORY

```
  public List<PRItems> GetPRdetailItem(int id)
    {
        connection();
        List<PRItems> pritemsList = null;
        pritemsList = db.Database.SqlQuery<PRItems>("EXEC [SP_GET_LIST_PR_ITEMS] @ConsumableId",
                 new SqlParameter("@ConsumableId", id)).ToList();

        return pritemsList;


    }

    public List<PRItems> GetItems()
    {

        List<PRItems> reqitems = new List<PRItems>();
        reqitems.Add(new PRItems { CONSUMABLE_ID = 1, QUANTITY = 0, MEASUREMENT_ID = 0, CONSUMABLE_CODE = "", ITEM_DESCRIPTION = "", STATUS = "", REMARKS = "" });
        return reqitems;

    }
```

How will I add the result of GetPRdetailItem method in GetItems method?

Please help me on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[List.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx)** to add list into another list.

Make the following change in your `Consumables` action method.

Instead of `listPr.Add(pritemRepo.GetPRdetailItem(tmp).ToList());` , use below line of code.

`listPr.AddRange(pritemRepo.GetPRdetailItem(tmp));`

and remove below line

`return RedirectToAction("AddPurchaseRequest");`

Comment: Indeed. `Add` accepts only a single item. Hence, your error. `AddRange` allows you to add multiple items.

Comment: @Krishnraj Rana- How will I add list into another list? The consumables list has its own page, and the other list is on another page.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - -I want to add the result of GetPRdetailItem method in GetItems method. The GetItems method is a list in another page, while the GetPRdetailItem is in the consumables page. How will I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i do not understand how get the data and what you want.But the mistake most possibly is at your for iterate of Consumables action method.your action method always return RedirectToAction("AddPurchaseRequest") at first iterate.When i =0 your action method finished.